# What is mask in HDFS folder permission

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, acl

I am hadoop user using Hadoop-2.6.0 in windows. I want to use Acls for folder level permissions. I don't understand the permissions on directories.[image]

Upto my knowledge, owner of the directory and the users in the supergroup have full access to the directory.

Then what is default user, group, other and mask delimited by **::**?? How HDFS checks for permission.

What is **mask**? Where, how and why is it used?

I referred [HDFS_Permissions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Access_Control_Lists) but not understand clearly. Help me to understand the usage and concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACLs are of the order `<type>:<name (optional)>:<permission>`.  If the name field is not populated, it applies to every user/group.  If the name is supplied, it will be supplemental to the entry without the name.  Meaning, in your example above, user permissions by default are `rw-`.  However, because user 'bruce' is also defined, his permissions are `rwx`.

However, the mask directive is also set.  From the HDFS Permission page, mask is defined as : ... a special ACL entry that filters the permissions granted to all named user entries and named group entries, and also the unnamed group entry.  What this means is it filters or overrides any named user/group entries as well as unnamed group entries.  This overrides the permissions for bruce to be `r--`.  That is why they note the effective permissions of `#r--`.

Group mapping is determined by the following from the HDFS Permission page : This implementation shells out with the bash -c groups command (for a Linux/Unix environment) or the net group command (for a Windows environment) to resolve a list of groups for a user.

Comment: If i remove the mask then what will happen? named entries will not be effective?

Comment: The mask overrides settings.  Removing the mask will make the the permissions act exactly as defined.

Comment: Thanks, but when creating a directory there will be user, group and other; but no mask. Setting acl to other:--- but still other users can access the directory. If i set the mask then it works fine (other users cannot access the dir). So it seems mask is required for default directives also.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this in the documentation, but you are correct that a mask must be defined otherwise it defaults to the union of permissions on all entries that would be filtered by the mask.  However, the 'mask' directive shouldn't have any affect on 'other' according to the documentation.  My guess is that the union of the named user/group and unnamed group permissions are matching your tests.  What does your permission file look like?

Comment: Yes as per documentation 'other' won't affect by mask. But we have to set a mask in order to make the 'other', 'user' be effective for permission check. All other definition are correct as in the documentation i think.

Comment: Yes, if 'other' isn't defined the union of named user/group and unnamed group permissions are used as the mask.  Without knowing what your ACL is defined as and what your user and their groups are that you are testing with, it's difficult to say exactly what you are experiencing.